# Заставить правильно работать message_handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть два куска кода в разных ботах, в первом он проверяет вводимую дату и при ошибке в формате даты предлагает ввести дату снова. Работает это через try-except

```
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMParam.checkin)  # Вводим дату начала чартера
async def load_checkin(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
  try:
    datetime.date.fromisoformat(message.text)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['checkin'] = message.text
    await FSMParam.next()
    await message.reply("дата окончания чартера 'ГГГГ-ММ-ДД'")
  except ValueError:
    await message.reply(f'Вы ввели не правильную дату, попробуйте еще раз! \n')
```

Во втором боте проверяется валидность номера телефона, вводить заново номер он не предлагает. Делается через if-else

```
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.phone_number)
async def load_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if validate_phone_number(message.text):
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['phone_number'] = message.text
            try:
                """ Проверка клиента на присутствие в базе данных """
                base_connect, cur = base_init()
                name, id_client = check_phone_number(data['phone_number'])
                base_close(base_connect)
                await message.answer(f'{name}, Вы вошли, запишитесь на консультацию.', reply_markup=kb_order)
            except:
                await message.answer(f"Вы не зарегистрированы в базе данных. Пройдите регистрацию.")
    else:
        await message.reply(
            f"Номер телефона невереного формата.\nПовторите ввод фамилии и номер телефона в формате +79876543210\nЖмите кнопку 'Вход'")
```

Функция проверки телефона:

```
def validate_phone_number(phone_number):
# Паттерн для проверки номера телефона в формате +7XXXXXXXXXX
pattern = r'^\+7\d{10}$'
if re.match(pattern, phone_number):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в рамках второй функции бот запрашивал заново номер телефона?

Answer (score 0):

Пропустил       await state.finish() ))
все заработало.